# How to get a session variable in a Spring Controller?

Tags: spring, hibernate, servlets

I have a Controller configured on Spring, and I have to workout a DB connection through it to call DAO operations.

This connection is actually available in a session variable, which is not accessible at the momment to the Spring Controller due to it is not HttpServlet inherited.

What is the right way to this Controller access the session variables? Must I implement methods doGet and doPost, inherited from HttpServlet, in order to manipulate the request object? Can it rattle Spring controll over the class?

Thanks for responding.

```
@Controller
public class SpringController {

    @RequestMapping("/create")
    public String form(MyCar myCar) {
                /*That's where I have to retrieve hibernateSession from
                * HttpSession and pass to DAO class do its work.
                */
                MyCarDAO myCarDao = new MyCarDAO(session);
                myCarDao.saveOrUpdate(myCar);
        return "WEB-INF/views/projeto/novo.jsp";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can inject the `HttpServletRequest` object: `private @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;` does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `HttpSession` parameter to your method:

```
@RequestMapping("/create")
public String form(MyCar myCar, HttpSession session) {
   ...
}
```

Spring will automatically add the `session` parameter when the method is called.

Check the documentation of [RequestMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) for possible parameters

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you declare 3 session attributes, but use only 1 of them in your handler method parameters, so:

```
@SessionAttributes({ "abc", "def", "ghi" })
public class BindingTestController {

    @ModelAttribute("abc")
    public String createABC() {
        return "abc";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void onGet(@ModelAttribute("abc") String something) {
        // do nothing :)
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void onPost(@ModelAttribute("abc") String something, BindingResult bindingResult, SessionStatus sessionStatus) {
        sessionStatus.setComplete();
    }

}
```

There are lots of example if hit it in google

Answer (score 0):

IMO Right way should be to store the connection in a session-scoped bean instead of a session variable.

Use 
@Scope(value = "session")

(cf. http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html)